# HTML: Terinary operator in option tag showing option as selected if it matches input

Tags: html, jsp, drop-down-menu, operators

```
<html>
    <head> </head>
    <body> 
        <select>
            <option value='one' ${Data.input == 11 ? "selected" : ""}>1</option>
            <option value='two' ${Data.input == 22 ? "selected" : ""}>2</option>
            <option value='three' ${Data.input == 3 ? "selected" : ""}>3</option>
            <option value='four' ${Data.input == 44 ? "selected" : ""}>4</option>
        </select>
    </body>
</html>
```

I am trying to show drop down value as selected when my parameter matches any of the values in the options.

Suppose if my Data.input is 3 then option 3 has to be selected as default when I open the page.
But it is not working.

P.S: I am new to web technologies. So please let me know if I am doing anything wrong.

**EDIT:**

I am using jsp and you can see the output at [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Amarnath510/XMSTf/)

Comment: What does the rendered HTML look like?

Comment: Yes, show us the resulting HTML and which option is selected.

Comment: is Data.input a number? Will your JSP cast it to number if not? Are you in a version of JSTL that allows you to leave out the <c:out...> ? if so, try `<c:out value="${Data.input == 11 ? 'selected' : ''}" />`

Comment: Are you sure you are getting the correct value from the `${Data.input}`?

Comment: @ExplosionPills I have edited the question. Pls see the JSFiddle link.

Comment: @MohammadAreebSiddiqui not PHP. I am using jsp.

Comment: @DigvijayYadav I am using JSP. For now suppose give 3 in place of Data.input. Then option 3 has to be selected rt? But it is not working. Can u look at the link I have provided.

Comment: @Che: Have you tried using the brackets `()` for conditions
`${(Data.input == 11) ? "selected" : ""}`?

Comment: @DigvijayYadav I have done like the following 
`<option value='one' ${(3 == 3) ? "selected" : ""}>3</option>` but still the page shows 1 as default.

Comment: Check if EL is ignored in the `deployment descriptor` or in the begining of your jsp page.

Comment: Also try to see the resultant html code from the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternate solution you can use the JSTL with EL:

```
<select>
    <option <c:if test="${Data.value == 1}">selected</c:if>> 1 </option>
    <option <c:if test="${Data.value == 2}">selected</c:if>> 2 </option>
    <option <c:if test="${Data.value == 3}">selected</c:if>> 3 </option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have done this using another approach but this answer made me to learn something.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming you are using JSP since you tagged JSP in your question.

Try this:

```
<html>
    <head> </head>
    <body> 
        <select>
            <option value='one' <%= Data.input == 1 ? "selected" : "" %>>1</option>
            <option value='two' <%= Data.input == 2 ? "selected" : ""%>>2</option>
            <option value='three' <%= Data.input == 3 ? "selected" : ""%>>3</option>
            <option value='four' <%= Data.input == 4 ? "selected" : ""%>>4</option>
        </select>
    </body>
</html>
```

Also I see that you say == 11, == 22, == 3, ==4. Should those be 1, 2, 3, 4?

Comment: Defeats the purpose of using EL.

Comment: @Che i think we can't do JSP in JsFiddle! can we guys?

Comment: I believe JSFiddle is for straight JS code. You are using a server-side language (JAVA/JSP) which JSFiddle doesn't load so you won't get correct results. Have you tried my code? Any Luck? If not I would try outputting whats in Data.input. Maybe its not set or set to something other than 11, 22, 3, 44?